Лучший инструмент для автоматизации и невидимых для сайта действий
Появилась идея сделать автоматизацию на сайте. Акцент на скрытность автоматизированных действий, чтобы сайт считал что работает пользователь. Что посоветуете, Playwrite или selenium(seleniumBase)? Вроде как селениум оставляет следы, но тем не менее остается довольно популярным. Что посоветуете?

Selenium или playwright одинаково выполнят ваши задачи, правильно подметили, что стандарт selenium является более популярным, если вы хотите смотреть в сторону анонимности, то можете поискать информацию об undetected-chromebrowser, также нужно будет учитывать количество запросов в секунду, передаваемые заголовки, монотонность действий вашего алгоритма.
Как итог, неважно что вы будете использовать, важно знать с кем вы воююте и какие алгоритмы обнаружения ботов использует ваш целевой сайт.
P.S. парсинг данных зачастую является не совсем законным и не этичным, все действия только с разрешения создателя сайта=)
